# How to stop sql query within python outputting to the terminal

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

So I've got a small project that I'm working on. When the sql portion of the script runs it outputs the result to now() to the terminal. Is there any way to stop this?

```
my_curson.execute("UPDATE ICA.user SET clockin=now() WHERE uid=%s", (u_scan,))
print "clocked in"
```

Output lin terminal looks like:

```
12118311672 Authorised
(datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 6, 18, 50, 16),)
clocked in
```

EDIT

```
if form == u_scan:
    print(u_scan + " Authorised")
    my_cursor.execute("SELECT clockin FROM ICA.user WHERE uid=%s", (u_scan,))
    isin = my_cursor.fetchall()
    for inis in isin:
        var1 = isin[0]
    if var1 == (None):
            my_cursor.execute("UPDATE ICA.user SET clockin=now() WHERE uid=%s", (u_scan,))
            print "clocked in"
            GPIO.output(12,1)
```

Comment: Please post fuller code block. `cursor.execute` usually does not print anything but raise exception. Likely another `print` is somewhere.

Comment: I've edited with more information.